# Add Extra space to the Word at right side in HTML Page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text-alignment

I need to add some after the word based on my custom actions.

For Example in the sentence, "I need to Walk"

I have to insert space only to the word "need" at right side.

I tried using word-space but it applies to entire tag but i want additional space only for a specific word.

How to achieve this javascript or any other method?

Comment: Why `need`? How do you identify the words that need an extra space?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Actually i need this one for an iPhone Application. In uiwebview whenever the user selects some word i will show the pop up. In that user have some set actions to do so based on that i need to flexibly add extra spaces to the word in right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specific word you need to pad out, a relatively simple solution is to place the word you need to add the space to into its own `<span>` and style the span with an appropriate `margin-right`.